# Code optimization for set of task with java

Tags: java

i have some java code as below

```
Product prod1 = new Product("product A");
List<String> prod1Patterns1 = List of("literal1", "literal2", "literal3"); //Just string literals which are specific to product A
List<String> prod1Pattern2 =  List of("1", "2", "3"); // Just string literals which are specific to product A
prod1.setprod1Patterns1(prod1Patterns1);
prod1.setprod1Pattern2(prod1Pattern2);
someotherfinalcollections.add(prod1);
```

i have like 1000 products for which i have to use above code . Could some one please suggest me some generic way to do this . so that a common functionality could be written to iterate over some collections and do this 
each product (out of 1000) has its own prodpatterns1 and prodpatterns2

Comment: Not enough information for profound answers. In any case, consider putting the data into some external storage, and **NOT** into the source code. (Use a database, or at least a file that you can load at runtime)

Comment: Missing information - where do you get those String literals from? If you're reading product names and lists of patterns from somewhere... Than the answer kind of shows itself. And if you have to write them by hand, than you're already doomed.

Comment: like the other comments, i have to agree there is far too little information

Comment: the string literals are not from DB but its hardcoded as they are predefined as of now. so is it good idea to have them refer from property file or something?